# How do I call pdb's Jump() command in PyCharm

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, pdb

I can't find a way to change the next command at runtime when debugging in PyCharm (see: http://pymotw.com/2/pdb/#jump-back),

This has been around in VS/PyTools for ages ("Set next statement"). Some people on JetBrains' forum said it was not possible but I'm not sure if they can be trusted... (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9537)

Do anyone has more information on the topic?

Comment: They say they'll think about implementing it.

Comment: Thx for the answer. It's really a feature I use a lot in when debbuging in VS. Do you use Pycharm yourself or do you have an other IDE with this feature to suggest ?

Comment: Does anyone know how to call the pdb jump command WHILE keeping the debug session in pycharm going?

Answer (score 0):

You currently can't. Here is the feature request, please upvote it - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14306

As far as "undoing" by going back lines to match a previous state, yes that is much harder. Just re-running the previous line shouldn't be too hard (understanding that it's not going to undelete or undo state changes)